# How to deploy a package for a private gitlab dependency in Yarn

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg

I am working on a vue project that needs to use another private vue project as a dependency. This other private project is a vue plugin.

I have found how to tell yarn to fetch a package on a private gitlab repository by adding the following line in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "myPackage": "git+https://{token-name}:{token}@gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git#someTag"
}
```

This works well, and the content of my repo is downloaded in my `node_modules`. However, here comes my problem :

In this repo, the actual vue plugin is not at the root, it's under a subfolder of the repo, meaning the `index.js` at the root of the repo is not the one from my plugin (and I guess it is the one yarn will be using).

I have a custom yarn deploy script that compiles my plugin into one JS file and put it in a `dist` folder, however the dist folder is not versioned. I can use the gitlab CI to generate it, but still i'm pretty sure yarn won't use what is inside the `dist` folder.

My (broad) question is : how can I use the tools at my disposition (yarn, gitlab-ci) to be able to use my private gitlab repository as a vue-plugin for one of my other project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would tell other packages how to use your packages by using the properties of your `package.json`. For instance, the [main declaration](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main)

```
{ 
    main: 'dist/index.js'
}
```

This tells node how to resolve your module from your package.

so `require('my-vue-plugin')` or `import MyVuePlugin from 'my-vue-plugin'` would resolve to `node_modules/my-vue-plugin/dist/index.js`, for example.

As far as versioning is concerned -- you don't version the file, or the folder. You version through the `version` property of your `package.json` and, in your case, through GIT by using `git tag -a v(major).(minor).(patch).`

The version that you tag should match the version that you specify in `package.json`.

I would recommend [reading more about semantic versioning](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) and [creating a script (like VueJS)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/scripts/release.sh) to auto-increment your package, version and publish.